# Не прогружается autoload.php после переноса сайта на хостинг

Tags: php, wordpress, функции, хостинг, autoload

Недавно перенес  сайт на хостинг, получаю ошибку. На локальном сервере все работает без ошибок.

Файл autoload в каталоге vendor присутствует.

стоит мне удалить файл functions.php, как отображается только скелет

а так сайт просто выдает сообщение об ошибке

последний лог:

"Ошибка с типом E_COMPILE_ERROR возникла на строке 14 файла /home/AP/web/*домен сайта*/public_html/wp-content/themes/*папка*/functions.php. Сообщение об ошибке: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/AP/web/*домен сайта*/public_html/wp-content/themes/*папка*/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')"

кроме того, сообщения о дальнейших ошибках почему-то не приходят на почту

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: 1. [Как правильно перенести сайт на WordPress?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/767562) 2. [Анатомия темы](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC#.D0.90.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.BC.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D0.A2.D0.B5.D0.BC.D1.8B)